# Is there a way to treat ajax requests different than user requests in .htaccess?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess

Let's say I have `/secret/example.php`
In my .htaccess file I want to rewrite requests to `/secret` to `/home.html` using

```
RewriteRule secret /home.html
```

But now when I try to access `/secret/example.php` using ajax from `example.js`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/secret/example.php', true);
xhr.onload = function(){
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send();
```

It is also redirected and does not work.

Is there a way I can only rewrite requests made by the user (by typing `www.example.com/secret` in the search bar) and still allow ajax to access the file?

Comment: You could simply set an additional header in your ajax requests which you evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you set additional header in xhr request: `xhr.setRequestHeader("VIAXHR", "true");`

Then in .htaccess something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIAXHR} !^true$
RewriteRule secret /home.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RewriteCond before RewriteRule

[RewriteCond documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secret/example.php$
RewriteRule secret /home.html
```